# How to format an array using a recordset for data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to populate an array with data from a database. I need it to have different labels from what is stated in database as headers.

This is how I need it to be formatted

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

I have used this but then I'm getting the wrong labels

```
$items = array();
while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) {
  $items[] = $row_Recordset1;
}
```

eg.

```
[{"ID":"2","ARTIST":"!!!"},...]
```

I need it like this to use the jquery ui plugin for autocomplete

Comment: that is JSON. Guess you know JSON right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the data as a `JSON` object...

```
$items = array();
while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) {
  $items[] = array(
    'label' => $row_Recordset1['ARTIST'],
    'value' => $row_Recordset1['ID']
  );
}

return json_encode($items);
```

Also you should look at using [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php) instead of `MySQL_*` functions as they are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch assoc data from your database, put them into an array and use `json_encode` on the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) method on your associative array.